# SSLContext is hanging in python 3.6.3

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am very new to python and as well as sto this forum. I had to create Http Server supported with tls1.2 security. Earlier we had python 2.6. Now we need tls1.2 security. python 2.6 does not support tls1.2 security. So we updated to python 3.6.3.

I have written sample code for http server handler but it is not working. when I tried to debug with print statement. It is not moving beyond SSLContext() function call. I googled a lot, but I didn't find any answer.

ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2) # This function calls hanging in python 3.6.3.

When I saw ssl.py file, I found that below function call is not responding. I am not how do I solve this issue. Expecting python experts help.

self = _SSLContext.**new**(cls, protocol)

[Hint: ssl.wrap_socket() function call works in pythong 2.6. But not working in python 3.6.3 version. After debugging I found that it is hanging at SSLContext() creation function call.]

I appreciate your help!!

## ---------------------Here is my complete code----------------------------------

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import ssl

httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 9449), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
print("Line 1")
sock = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2) // This line hangs
print("Line 2")
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, certfile='/tmp/cert-and-key.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer from github.com. It may be useful for someone so I am posting the link.

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/12077

Thank you!!